# Problem in adding navbar animate out animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

```js
  const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);
```

```css
@keyframes appear {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(100%);

    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

.mNavBar{
    animation: appear 200ms ease-in forwards;
}
```

```html
{isMenuOpen ?  <div className="mNavBar" ></div> : null}
```

I want to add animate out animation to my navBar. I tried doing it with toggling class and adding animate out i.e translateX(-100%) but when page loads navBar somehow remains open for a second and then translates out even if isMenuOpen is false by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with element's className rather than add/remove the whole element. For example:

```
// The state:  
const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

// The element:
<div className={`mNavBar ` + (isMenuOpen && `open`)}></div>

// The styles:
    .mNavBar{
        transition: transform 200ms;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
        // the rest of your styles
    }
    .mNavBar.open{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
```